# Linear Properties of the Quantile Function

Tags: self-study, linear, quantile-regression, quantiles

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with continuous distribution function $F(x)$ and quantile function $Q_X(p)$ and let $Y = aX + b$ for some constants $a > 0$ and $b$.

How can I prove that $Q_Y(p) = a\, Q_X(p) + b$?

Comment: If applicable, please consider adding the `self-study` tag and reading its [wiki page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the probability that $X<Q_x(p)$ is $p$.  Given that $Y$ is linearly related to $X$, can you now write a similar expression for $Y$?